# OnGetDayStateStart of CMonthCalCtrl and memory allocation

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, monthcalendar

The [`NMDAYSTATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-nmdaystate) states for `prgDayState`:

> Address of an array of `MONTHDAYSTATE` values. The buffer at this address must be large enough to contain at least `cDayState` elements. The first element in the array corresponds to the date in `stStart`.

I asked ChatGPT and it is clearly wrong for this:

```
void CMyCalendar::OnGetDayState(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMDAYSTATE* pDayState = reinterpret_cast<NMDAYSTATE*>(pNMHDR);
    // Allocate an array of MONTHDAYSTATE structures
    MONTHDAYSTATE* pDayStateArray = new MONTHDAYSTATE[pDayState->cDayState];
    // Assign the address of the array to the prgDayState member
    pDayState->prgDayState = pDayStateArray;
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    *pResult = 0;
    // Delete the prgDayState array
    delete[] pDayStateArray;
}
```

It suggests allocating dynamically but then says to **delete** it. The official docs does not make this clear about allocation / deallocation.

In my code I am using `mdStates[4]{};`.

---

I still have a fundamental issue here. On my PC it shows 2 calendras but on a clients PC it shows 3. So my `mdState` array is not large enough.

- Should I be declaring the array with `new` based on `cDayState`.
- - Will the system own it?

As I expected, this causes memory leaks:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnGetDayStateCalendarRange(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    NMDAYSTATE      *pDayState = reinterpret_cast<NMDAYSTATE*>(pNMHDR);
    //MONTHDAYSTATE mdState[4]{}; // 1 = prev 2 = left 3 = right 4 = next
    MONTHDAYSTATE *mdState = new MONTHDAYSTATE[pDayState->cDayState];


    if (pDayState != nullptr)
    {
        const COleDateTime  datStart(pDayState->stStart);
        InitDayStateArray(pDayState->cDayState, &mdState[0], datStart);
        pDayState->prgDayState = &mdState[0];
    }

    if (pResult != nullptr)
        *pResult = 0;
}
```

At the moment I increased the size to 8 for the array and this prevents the crash and I have no memory leaks since not using `new`.

Comment: I would still like to know if there is a way to compute what size array you need. Thank you.